# Are "in addition", "moreover", "furthermore" and "besides" all wrong in my sentences?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I want to know if "in addition", "moreover", "furthermore" and "besides" all don't work here because they are used when we have two things that both indicate the same thing. But here the first and second sentences seem to talk about two different things. I want to know if they are all wrong in my sentences.

> While female participation was highest in the 45-54 age bracket, that
> of males peaked among 15- to 24-year-olds. **In
> addition/Moreover/Furthermore/Besides**, a higher percentage of women than men
> exercised regularly in every age group except the youngest.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In addition", "moreover", "furthermore"  are all fine.

"Besides" as a linking adverb seem a little too conversational for this use.  it is okay to use Besides as a preposition and say something like "Besides this difference..."

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But I read sample sentences in the dictionary. It seems that "in addition", "moreover", and "furthermore" are used to say the two different aspects of the same thing. For example, the whole report is badly written. **Moreover**, it's inaccurate. But my sentences don't talk about the same thing.

Comment: No, they can all be used to link a sentence which adds some more related information or   gives further details about the same general topic. The general topic here is "differences between men and women's exercise" The peak age difference is one piece of info, the fact that women are ahead of men is a further piece of info about the topic.

Comment: Thanks again. These two new sentences have the same general topic, which is school spending. Therefore, "in addition" is suitable?  Teachers’ salaries accounted for the biggest school expenditure in all three years. **In addition**, furniture and equipment overtook other workers’ salaries as the second-largest expenditure by 2002.

Comment: A native speaker told me that I shouldn't use "in addition" in the school spending example. I'm so confused. Some native speakers are stricter than others.

Comment: Yes, some native speakers are stricter than others.  Some native speakers have opinions about grammar and rhetoric that are wrong.  English speakers aren't a hive mind, we are not borg.  My answer stands, which I think is useful and correct, others can write different answers. I would be happy to use "In addition" in your example on school spending.